# Package Delay (Theory)

Tags: ethernet, network, layer2

I have a question to the following excercise that I have from school.

> How big is the delay of a package if it gets send via satelite (~35km above earth)?

I assume I need to calculate this one. However I have no other values so I don't really know if this really can be calculated?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions or help about homework, examinations or certifications are off-topic here.

Comment: Here's also a good read: [https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/is-there-a-difference-between-latency-and-speed](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/is-there-a-difference-between-latency-and-speed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the distance to be covered and the speed of the signal.

The distance of an arbitrary point on the globe to a point above the equator can be calculated by the cosine rule. The speed of the signal - well, you've probably got that.

btw: geostationary orbit is 35,786 km above the equator, so it's more like ~36,000 km. 35 km is well within the atmosphere, much too low for a satellite (about 50% higher than the normal flight altitude of an SR-71 and somewhat below Baumgartner's and Eustace's stratosphere 'space' dives).